# how to execute Future payments on server-side using Meta data ID

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have **Authorization Code** & **Metadata ID** using mobile SDK
but I don't know how to use this in future payment using Paypal future payment method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented in the [Mobile SDK GitHub documentation](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md#create-a-payment).  It includes a step by step tutorial, and examples on how to correctly execute a payment.